# php strange looping problem

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Sorry for the long code, I'm really losing it.

This code is supposed to get a list of urls through POST, in a textarea with breaklines between each url. The script should download each url, go through the html and take some links, then go in those links, get some data and echo it out.

For some reason, **visually** it looks as if I'm running `getDetails()` only once, as I'm getting only one set of results.

**I have checked multiple times if the `foreach` loop takes each url separately and that part is working**

Can anyone spot the problem?

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

function getDetails($html) {
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $dom->load($html);
    $title = $dom->find('h1', 0)->find('a', 0);
    foreach($dom->find('span[style="color:#333333"]') as $element) {
       $address = $element->innertext;
    }
    $address = str_replace("<br>"," ",$address);
    $address = str_replace(","," ",$address);
    $title->innertext = str_replace(","," ",$title->innertext);

    if ($address == "") {
        $exp = explode("<strong><strong>",$html);
        $exp2 = explode("</strong>",$exp[1]);
        $address = $exp2[0];
    }

    echo $title->innertext . "," . $address . "<br>";
}

function getHtml($Url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.google.com/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}

function getdd($u) {
    $html = getHtml($u);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $dom->load($html);
    foreach($dom->find('a') as $element) {
       if (strstr($element->href,"display_one.asp")) {
            $durls[] = $element->href;
       }
    } 
    return $durls;
}

if (isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $urls = explode("\n",$_POST['url']);
    foreach ($urls as $u) {
        $durls2 = getdd($u);
        $durls2 = array_unique($durls2);
        foreach ($durls2 as $durl) {
            $d = getHtml("http://www.example.co.il/" . $durl);
            getDetails($d);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the $_POST['url'] might look like? I don't really get what you are trying to do.

Comment: get some debugging output in there.  echo count($urls)."\n"; at the outer loop, echo "\t".count($durls2)."\n"; at the middle loop, and echo "\t\t".$durl."\n"; at the inner loop.  That will tell you how many times the loops are actually running, and then we can figure out where it is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You're only assigning the last element in the loop, it looks like.  You'll need to concatenate.  Something like `$address .= $element->innertext;` inside the loop (note the .= instead of =).

edit: unless I'm mistaking what it's supposed to be doing.  I think I may've been focusing on the wrong part of the code.

Comment: That part is actually ok, I need the last $element->innertext, so no need to concatenate there. problem is it visually looks like I'm running getDetails() only once, as I get only one set of results

Comment: Sorry, once I posted that I figured I was probably not reading it right anyway.  But I just tried it without the curl stuff and it seemed to loop fine, though I don't know how it could've interfered.

Answer (score 0):

When you use DOMDocument on html you load it with `$dom->loadHTMLFile()` or `$dom->loadHTML()` you should also call `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` before hand so that it will not crash because of improperly formatted html.